# How can I run several schedule using quartz with spring configuration

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

In my situation, clients are allowed to schedule a  job. As I can see, quartz often use a cronExpression to perform a schedule. But there are many clients with many schedules, I can't write many trigger beans cuz I don't know how many schedules really are, it depends on clients. So, would some one help?

Comment: You should distinguish definition of Trigger vs Job, many jobs can use the same Trigger. What's the real problem?

Comment: Then you should dynamically re-create triggers for the job for different clients. [Example](http://darthanthony.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/dynamic-scheduling-with-javaspring/).

Comment: "Wire up a SchedulerFactoryBean as above.  We will use this bean wired Spring service to create our schedules with." is this necessary, as mentioned in the Example above. what about StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is designed to add and remove jobs and triggers at runtime. Spring is a degenerated case where all triggers and jobs are defined at startup time. In Quartz, when having an instance of `Scheduler` you can easily create, browse and delete triggers at your wish, example from [How-To: Scheduling a Job](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/ScheduleJob):

```
// Define job instance
JobDetail job1 = newJob(ColorJob.class)
    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .build();

// Define a Trigger that will fire "now", and not repeat
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .startNow()
    .build();

// Schedule the job with the trigger 
schedulder.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

See the [official documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start), especially the [cookbook](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/).

Also distinguish between jobs (a piece of code wrapped in a class that should be executed) and a trigger (time condition under which job is executed). Remember that by default when last trigger associated with the job (job can have several triggers) fires, the job is removed from the scheduler.